# Is it possible to access via shell to connected Ipad

Tags: ios, ipad

I have connected my IPad to my Mac for debugging my app.
My app stores data the the document folder, which I would like to check without handling with the IPad directly.

Is it possible to access the folders of the connected IPda with a shell from Mac ? If not how can I browse and read files from IPad using the MAC ? I can't see the device in Finder.

Comment: This isn't really the place for software related questions. Shell access will only work if your device is jailbroken afaik. One can use iExplorer (google for it) to access the public filesystem on the iOS device

Comment: You can do it from (OSX) iTunes, can't you?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I can after you suggested :-) Thanks also for the good hint IExplorer. I am a MAC newbie.